boost asio UDP socket receive "Netork is unreachable" error. is it recoverable?
I'm using boost wrapper of UDP socket to communicate with remote server. Here's the initialization flow of that socket (omitting error handling for ease of reading.)
std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> socket

socket = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(ioctx);

socket->open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), ec);

boost::asio::ip::address server = boost::asio::ip::make_address(
     server_ip, ec);

boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(server, port);

socket->connect(endpoint);

After initialization, I read data from the socket and on some rare occasions I see it the "Network is Unreachable" error code which is not part of socket recv syscall.
auto bytes = socket->receive(
             boost::asio::buffer(packet->get_pkt(), 
             packet->get_buffer_size()), 
             0,
-->          ec);

So I wonder if boost library add this error in the wrapper, and whether I can continue using this socket or have to re-create the connection.
Thanks !

Udp is connectionless. There is no such thing as "recreate the connection"

Agree, but maybe do you know from where do I get the "Network is Unreachable" error... I've read that it's usually used in ping when you ICMP reaches a node that doesn't know what to do with the packet according to its routing table. so it generate a response with "Network is Unreachable" error... does boost perform it on the background when attempt to read from the socket ?

I can only speculate on this... is there something going on with the network? Like, for example, you're on a WLAN and it just goes down for a second? The thing is, I can imagine that the UDP socket is still bound to a specific network interface, possibly even the one that handles traffic to the address that you "connect" to. While it can't know whether that actually works, if the actual network interface goes down it knows that it won't work, so maybe that's causing it to give such errors even on receive...

One similar situation I ran into this kind intermittent network reconfiguration was with docker. Sometimes when a particular container was restarting periodically it caused a general network configuration reset even on my host's interfaces leading to frequent ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED messages in Chrome.

So, network_unreachable (ENETUNREACH or 9916) is never raised explicitly in Boost code.
If you're on windows it might be translated from

0x2742 returned by ::GetLastError().
WSAENETUNREACH_ when translated to the error_condition

The only place where the error is explicitly mentioned is in complete_iocp_connect, where it translates IOCP specific errors.
I would assume you're on POSIX because you mentioned syscalls.

Destination Unreachable
This ICMP documentation page clarifies:

Summary: Network Unreachable

Is the specified destination address a valid network?
Is the link up from the router sending the Network Unreachable message?
Is the port in the router configured with the correct address mask value?

[...]
Summary: Host Unreachable

You are assured that the intervening communications infrastructure is working properly.
Is the specified destination address the correct address for the host?
Is the host currently on-line and active?
Are there any physical problems on the destination network.


UDP is conceptually very similar to ICMP (as in they're datagram protocols on the same layer). I strongly encourage you to read the entire linked page, as it gives you many real life scenarios that can typically cause the particular error condition to be reported.
Summary
A syscall will be returning ENETUNREACH. The conditions for that to happen is when the interface implied by your address/masks are (temporarily) not (correctly) configured. See whether some system process is causing periodic network changes.
